# Swap symbol instances with another symbol

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've used the Symbol Sprayer in Illustrator to create a huge pile of symbol instances. I expanded the object so now I have many instances of those symbols in a group. I duplicated the group, and now I want to make all the instances in the second group point to a new symbol.

How do I say "Given these symbol instances that I have selected, please change them to be instances of a different symbol"? I've looked through all options in the Symbols palette, as well as the context menu for the selected items, and I can see nothing relevant.

<sub>(I'm using Adobe Illustrator CC 2015.3.1 Release, version 20.1.0 64-bit, on Windows 7x64, in case it matters.)</sub>

Comment: Of course I find the answer as soon as I post the question. Isn't that so often the case?

Comment: Murphy strikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the symbols selected, look in the Control panel *(normally docked right under the menu bar; use **Window ▶ Control** to show it, if hidden)* for the "Replace" option. Click on this drop down to show your loaded symbols, and pick a new one.

[[image: screenshot of the controls panel with Replace symbol open]

*<sup>click for larger image</sup>*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R3S2.png)